# Google Spreadsheet Creation - Node.js

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to create new google spreadsheet using the google spreadsheet api using node.js

I have managed to get the Google OAuth 2.0 working, where I am getting the access tokens for the clients.

Now on searching the Google API docs there are example using the gData client library but nothing giving me pointers to node.js

Here are my findings for creating a new google spreadhseet

1. Upload a spreadsheet manually  OR
2. Use a resumable upload link

There is not much information on the resumable upload link.

I can see the HTTP Post Request and Response but I do not understand how to construct the post request in node.js

EDIT--

I am reading [Google Apps Platform](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#creating_a_new_document_or_file_with_metadata_only)

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do it with the [`create`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create) method of the [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts) (currently v4).

This code examples does not use any 3rd party libraries, it uses [`googleapis`: Google API's official Node.js client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis)

```
const google = require('googleapis');
const sheets = google.sheets('v4');

// authenticate, and store that authentication, in this example
// it is stored in a variable called `auth`. I am using JWT 
// authentication, but you can use the any form of authentication

const auth = new google.auth.JWT(
  key.client_email,
  null,
  key.private_key,
  ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'], // make sure that your auth scope includes `spreadsheets`, `drive` or `drive.file`
  null
);

sheets.spreadsheets.create({
  auth: auth,
  resource: {
    properties: {
      title: 'Title of your new spreadsheet'
    }
  }
}, (err, response) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(`The API returned an error: ${err}`);
    return;
  }

  console.log('Created a new spreadsheet:')
  console.log(response);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to know is how to construct post request, then check this example

http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

Comment: I am aware of how to do a post request in node.js. I want to know if at all i am to make a post request to google for creating a new spreadhsheet,  to what link should I do the post and what should I post

Answer (score 0):

Checkout

https://github.com/EastCloud/node-spreadsheets/

EastCloud has written a friendly-ish wrapper around the Google Docs/Drive API

Answer (score 0):

**If you are new and want to get and add data to Google spreadsheets, please refer below link to get step-by-step guide.**

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/03/google-spreadsheets-and-javascriptnode-js.html

I was tested same in recent nodejs project