# How to Create New Google Spreadsheet Using googleapis in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets-api

I want to create a new Google Spreadsheet using [googleapis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis) package.

Thanks to [Daniel Apt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44359330/12552441), I am able to create the blank file of it. But I want to give the file values.

I tried this way

```
const createOption = {
  resource: {
    properties: {
      title: 'Ini judul spreadsetnya'
    },
    values: ['a']
  }
}
```

But it said that `Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "values" at 'spreadsheet': Cannot find field.`. What field should I add to insert the values? And how do I create the spreadsheet in specific folder? Thank you.

Comment: Per [the docs](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create), there is indeed no values field in a Spreadsheet object. I'd guess any data will be inside the sheets array, but maybe spend some time exploring the structure the API expects.

Comment: Thank you @jonrsharpe for the documentation. Now I realized something.

Answer (score 2):

## What you are trying to accomplish:

- You want to create a new spreadsheet with specific values.
- You want this spreadsheet to be created on a specific folder on Google Drive.

## Solution:

The first step to accomplish this is to understand why you can't use the `values` property in your request.

Looking into the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create#request-body) you can see that the request is supposed to be of an instance `Spreadsheet`, and this type does not contain values.

You can also see that there is no way to specify where the spreadsheet will be created, since the [`Spreadsheet` resource](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#resource:-spreadsheet) does not contain any reference to it's parent folder.

If we break it down, you actually want to do three things:

- Create a new spreadsheet
- Move it to a specific folder
- Fill it with values

Note: You can do step 1 and 2 with a single API call

### Create a new spreadsheet:

Change your request body to be like the following:

```
const createOption = {
  resource: {
    properties: {
      title: 'Ini judul spreadsetnya'
    }
  }
};
```

### Move the spreadsheet to another folder

You will need to use the Drive API to move a file.

You do this by updating the file to have another parent. In this case, you will use the [`file.update` call with the `addParents` option](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update#parameters) where you can add a comma-separated list of parentIds.

These parentIds are the Ids of the folder your file should belong to. (Yes, you can have it in multiple places).

You can extract these [via API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list?apix_params=%7B%22q%22%3A%22mimeType%20%3D%20%27application%2Fvnd.google-apps.folder%27%22%7D) or thru the interface:

[image: How to select the file Id from a folder.]

Here is how your request should look like:

```
const driveMoveOption = {
  fileId: "", //You will insert this later
  addParents: "<YOUR PARENT ID HERE>",
  removeParents: "root" //To remove it from the "MyDrive" section
}
```

And here is a sample of how to use it:

```
sheets.spreadsheets.create(createOption, function (err, response) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }

  //response contains the `Spreadsheet` resource we want, with it's fileId
  driveMoveOption.fileId = response.spreadsheetId; //Set the spreadsheet Id to 
  drive.files.update(driveMoveOption, function (err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }

    //response contains the structure of a Files structure: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource
  });
});
```

### Creating a spreadsheet on a specific folder

If you use the Drive.files.create API instead you can use this request:

```
{
  "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
  "name": "Test",
  "parents": [
    "<YOUR PARENT ID HERE>"
  ]
}
```

and call it with

```
const driveCreateAndMoveOption = {
  "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
  "name": "Test",
  "parents": [
    "<YOUR PARENT ID HERE>"
  ]
};

drive.files.update(driveCreateAndMoveOption, function (err, response) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }

  //response contains the structure of a Files structure. Use this to get the file ID for the spreadsheet call.
});
```

### Insert your custom values

The request to insert values on your spreadsheet should look something like this:

```
const appendOption = {
  "spreadsheetId": "", //You will insert this later
  "range": "A:A",
  "valueInputOption": "USER_ENTERED",
  "resource": {
    "values": [
      [
        "a"
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

To use the correct `SpreadsheetId`  you will need to run this code **after** you create it, and use that number.

This can be done like this:

```
sheets.spreadsheets.create(createOption, function (err, response) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }

  //response contains the `Spreadsheet` resource we want, with it's fileId
  appendOption.spreadsheetId = response.spreadsheetId; //Set the spreadsheet Id to insert the values on.
  sheets.spreadsheets.values.append(appendOption, function (err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }

    //response contains the structure detailed on: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append#response-body

  });
});
```

Comment: I think that your flow is better for being simpler request body. In your flow, 3 API calls are required. If I can modify your flow, how about this modification? 1. Directly create new Spreadsheet to the specific folder using the files.create method of Drive API. 2. Put the values to the created Spreadsheet using the values.append method of Sheets API. In this case, 1 API call can be reduced.

Comment: By the way, in your script, I think that an error occurs at `Drive.Files.update`. I'm not sure about `Drive` in your whole script. But `Files` is `files` if you use googleapis. And if you want to use the files.update method, in your request body of `driveMoveOption`, the created file has 2 parents. So how about adding `removeParents: "root"` to `driveMoveOption`? By this, the Spreadsheet created to the root folder is moved to the specific folder of `addParents`. If I misunderstood your flow and script, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike thanks for taking the time to review my answer. Please feel free to update it with those points in mind. Good job keeping the community healthy and well informed! :)

Answer (score -2):

So as [jonrsharpe's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59641637/how-to-create-new-google-spreadsheet-using-googleapis-in-node-js#comment105444672_59641637) comment, finally I tried to create the blank spreadsheet and update it (there are two command call).